# SQL Server INSERT INTO table xp_cmdshell - multiple lines in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've currently got the below as part of a larger query to import data from files. At the moment it takes each line of the file its reading and puts it in its own row. Is there a way to put it all in a single row?

```sql
SET @command = 'type D:\ebay\'+@filename+'"'
INSERT INTO content
EXEC xp_cmdshell @command
```

Comment: No, at least not directly with `xp_cmdshell`, because even if you do send a command that gives it all in one line, the limit of the result set (`varchar(255)`) means you (typically) couldn't insert it in one row that way. Consider using `OPENROWSET(BULK ..., SINGLE_NCLOB)` instead (it doesn't accept variables so the statement will have to be constructed dynamically).

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do this with the below if anyone is interested :)

```sql
    --Merges multiple rows into single row
    INSERT INTO #content2
    SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT CHAR(13) + content
        FROM #content1
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')


    SELECT TOP 1 @description = content FROM #content2
    
    INSERT INTO #descriptions (SKU, Description) VALUES (REPLACE(@filename, '.html', ''), @description)
```